# Как сделать так что бы пользователь вводил данные а они сохранялись в отдельной переменной aiogram python

Tags: python, telegram-bot, бот, aiogram

бот присылает сообщение "Есть ли вам 18 лет" у пользователь есть две кнопки "да" "нет" пользователь выбирает вариант происходит проверка через if если да то у пользователя спрашивают его точный возраст и его возраст сохраняется в новую переменную. И мне нужно та часть кода которая будет сохранять в переменную возраст

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Почитайте про машину состояний в aiogram

Answer (score 0):

Ето очень тупо сохранять значение юзера в переменную

Используйте SQLite3 или хотя-бы JSON

Вот пример:

```
import sqlite3 as sql

con = sql.connect(<разположение файла>.db)
cur = con.cursor()

cur.execute('CREATE TABLE "users"("user_id" INT, "age18" TEXT)')
```

Ну если хотите подробнее, пишите мне в тг `@Orange_ADM`

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).